# How to send messages after one hour using React and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a chat app with React and Firebase and I'm using functional React components. Please I would like to find out if there is a way to send a user an email if a message has not been read after one hour. I'm using triggerEmail to send emails when a property is created like this:

```
const formik = useFormik({
... //some other code here
onSubmit: async (values) => {
... //some other code here
await addDoc(collection(db, "mail"), {
                        to: values.email,
                        template: {
                            name: 'Property Uploaded',
                            data: {
                                id: values.id
                            }
                        }
                    })
        }
    })
```

This code runs when a property is created and an email is sent to the user as well as the admin. There's also a chat feature where users can send messages to the admin and this is wrapped in a custom react hook.

```
export default function useSendMessage() {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const { user } = useAuthContext()
    const sendMessage = async (admin, agent, message) => {
        setError(null)
        try {
            await addDoc(collection(db, "messages", admin.id, "messages"), {
                admin: admin,
                agent: agent,
                isSender: admin.id === user.uid,
                message: message.trim(),
                markRead: false,
                created_at: moment().format()
            })
            await addDoc(collection(db, "messages", agent.id, "messages"), {
                admin: admin,
                agent: agent,
                isSender: agent.id === user.uid,
                message: message.trim(),
                markRead: false,
                created_at: moment().format()
            })
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error.message)
        }
    }

    return { error, sendMessage }
}
```

And I'm using this hook in the chat app like this:

```
import useSendMessage from "../../hooks/useSendMessage";
export default function UserMessageInput({ admin, agent }) {
...//some code here
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setSending(true)
        setMessage("")
        await sendMessage(admin, agent, message)
            .then(() => {
                setSending(false)
            })
    }
  return(
    ...//chat app UI
   )
}
```

Is there a way to trigger the email service if markRead is false after one hour? I would like to notify the admin or the agent that they have a new message on the site. I'm not sure setTimeout or setInterval can work because the agent or the admin might be offline at certain times.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule a Cloud Function to run in exactly one hour after the message doc has been created, as explained in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a) titled "How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL)".

Concretely, in the HTTP callback function that is invoked by Cloud Tasks you will first check the value of the `markRead` boolean field in the Firestore document and, if it is `false`, you'll send the email by creating a doc in the `mail` collection, since you use the Email extension.

Another approach would be to use a scheduled Cloud Function to run e.g. every minute, checking is the message was create more than one hour ago and is not marked as read. The above referred article explains the drawbacks of this approach.

Comment: Your comment was really helpful, though the article you referenced didn't help me much as it was written in typescript, but I finally found a workaround for it by creating a scheduled Cloud Function. I used the onCreate method on the Cloud Firestore Triggers as found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

Comment: Hey @AwesomeBassey, glad I could help you. I'm not sure to understand why you use a Cloud Function triggered by a Firestore document creation. If you want to goo for the [schedule Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) approach, you need to trigger it as follows: `functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun(...)` and in this cloud function find all the message documents that are older than one hour with markRead = false. So in the Scheduled Cloud Function you need to query your Firestore database.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this out since it's a more modular approach. I had spent so much time tinkering back and forth so I just used the Cloud Function Trigger with a setTimeout as a workaround, but I will also look into implementing this one you just referenced

Comment: Hey @AwesomeBassey did you have time to check as mentioned above? You may accept my answer if it helped you.